# Javascript defined object check

Tags: javascript

is 
  `mainobj.object_1 = mainobj.object_1 || []`

better than

`if (mainobj.object_1 == undefined){
    mainobj.object_1 = [];
}`

in the first example it would seem javascript would reassign its value to itself but maybe not.

in additon with the first example will reassign its own value to itself or not do anything it has a value?

Comment: I'd go for the first option because it is shorter and looks better.

Comment: The two examples you provided are not exactly equivalent. The first is preferred for brevity.

Comment: First option is not correct always

Comment: The second example could be rewritten `if (!mainobj.object_1){ mainobj.object_1 = []; }` to closer match the first example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best would be

```
if(typeof mainobj.object_1 === "undefined"){
    mainobj.object_1 = [];
}
```

But if you want to check for null too, then you **must add** null check as well.

First approach may lead to something undesired. Consider the below example

```
var mainobj = {};
mainobj.object_1 = false;
mainobj.object_1 = mainobj.object_1 || [];
alert(mainobj.object_1);
```

Here the alert reads empty instead of false. Remember `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `""` *(empty string)*, `NaN` are all false in Javascript.

Also, you need to keep in mind that `undefined` is **not** a reserved word in javascript

Comment: Reason for down vote will be appreciated !! I really don't know what is wrong with the answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if its just undefined you have to use the second example, because javascript return false if the object is null, empty string, zero, undefined, NaN or false.

so its about what exactly you want from your code.

Comment: What case would you recommend solution 1?

Answer (score -1):

They do almost the same thing.

```
mainobj.object_1 = mainobj.object_1 || []
```

Will look at `mainobj.object_1` to see if it's not `undefined` and not `null`, else assign it `[]`;

```
if (mainobj.object_1 == undefined){ mainobj.object_1 = []; }
```

This is going to do type coercion to `mainobj.object_1` before comparing it with `undefined`. Also  generally better to use `===` strict comparison rather than `==`, it is faster and more explicit. And IF you were to use strict comparisons, you'd have to adjust your statement to:

```
if (mainobj.object_1 === undefined || mainobj.object_1 === null){ mainobj.object_1 = []; }
```

As for coding preferences, developers would prefer the shorter form `mainobj.object_1 = mainobj.object_1 || [];` because it's terse and easy to read.

Comment: What will happen if mainobj.object_1 == false ?

Comment: @hop If you have to check for every data type and seeing if someone else has messed with your object, then there are more important issues to deal with.

Comment: But, definitely not an issue to ignore

Comment: @hop It's very difficult to detect, because someone could have an object defined there and you think it might be yours, it might even  have the exact same property names. It would wreak havoc for sure, and no one will know until runtime. _"If it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, then it's a duck."_

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct. First one is neat. 
But in the second one, you should use `===` instead of `==` to check for type as well.

Comment: Why not throw in a `typeof` check to check for type? `if (typeof mainobj.object_1 == "undefined")`

Comment: You shouldn't use `===`, you're trying to check for a falsey value, not specifically `undefined`, which is what the first example does.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen In fact it doesn't make any difference when `mainobj` is defined.

Comment: Yes. `typeof mainobj.object_1 === 'undefined'` will also be correct. If there is anything wrong with my original answer, I would like to know.

Comment: i think the problem with your answer is that there is no need for `===` unless a possible value of the variable is the string 'undefined'

Comment: @RobM. fwiw it is always better to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: In my answer I told phpdev76 to do `mainobj.object_1 === undefined` not `mainobj.object_1 === 'undefined'`. My answer will check for the value `undefined` not `"undefined"` (string).

Comment: @VisioN. that seems pretty subjective, what if I am counting on the implicit type coercion? As a general rule, I use `===` for just about everything, but I wouldn't say "never" use `==`

Comment: It's not always better to use `===`. What if the goal is to check for any falsey value? `mainobj.object_1 === undefined || mainobj.object_1 === false || mainobj.object_1 === null || mainobj.object_1 === '' || mainobj.object_1 === 0 || mainobj.object_1 === Number.NaN`. I think that is what the original question asks for.

Comment: @RobM."i think the problem with your answer is that there is no need for === unless a possible value of the variable is the string 'undefined'". That's not 100% true. If the value is `null` then `mainobj.object_1 == undefined` is true.